# Implementing auto logout

Tags: php, javascript, html, web-applications

I need a way to auto log out a user after 10 minutes of inactivity. This includes when they leave the browser.

I use this code for all pages that require log in:

```
function CheckLogin()
{
     if(!isset($_SESSION))
     { 
     session_start();

     }


     $sessionvar = $this->GetLoginSessionVar();

     if(empty($_SESSION[$sessionvar]))
     {
        return false;
     }
     return true;
}
```

Also, previous ways I've done it is it would require one to go back to the homepage and then they would be auto logged out. Is it possible that they don't need to go back to the page?

Comment: Was any of the answer helpful to you? If so, please mark one of them as accepted http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 4):

Yes. `session.gc_maxlifetime` is exactly what you are looking for:

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 600);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime

Comment: Where would I initialize it? Right in the CheckLogin()? How to redir to logout page? Thank you!

Comment: Your redirect can be handled by checking if the user is logged in on each page load and redirecting if not.  Or do you want a realtime solution?

Comment: @KalonCheong I would call it with my other PHP settings / configuration options. Preferably at the top of the script, but as long as it's set before calling `session_start()` you'll be fine.

Comment: @Stieffers Can there be a realtime solution to redirect?

Comment: @KalonCheong check out the jQuery plug-in Jim linked mentioned.

Comment: @Stieffers Does this method work, such that. For example, if I navigate away to Google for 10 minutes. I would be logged off?

Comment: @KalonCheong I think you're working under some erroneous assumptions.  If you navigate away to Google for 10 minutes and then come back to the page, you will have made another server side request which will mean that your session has already expired on the backend causing a redirect.  The only way the jQuery plugin comes into play is if you have an inactive browser window/tab open on your page for 10 minutes.  After the ten minutes the plugin can refresh the page or whatever thereby creating another backend request which would register you as logged out (since it's been 10 minutes).

Comment: @Stieffers How would you do it with the gc_maxlifetime? I editted my PHP.ini, and nothing happens. Also Is it suppose to be 600 rather then 10 since it's in seconds or is it in minutes? Thanks alot Stieffers, you are a big help. I am still getting used to web development.

Comment: @KalonCheong I'll write up a more detailed answer in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to go about implementing your timeout.  One from the server side and one from the client side.  Arguably the server side implementation is more important as the client side functions only offer a more enjoyable user experience, and don't actually interact with your application's authentication in anyway.

**Server Side**

You'll need a login check function which ensures the user is logged in.  You've mentioned a psuedo function in your question, so I'll just expand from there.

```
 function CheckLogin()
 {
      // Is the user logged in?
      if(session does not exist)
      {
           // redirect
           // redirect or return false
      }
      else
      {
           if(session is valid)
           {
                // user is logged in
                // redirect or return true
           }
           else
           {
                // redirect or return false
           }
      }
 }
```

**Client Side**

You'll need jquery, and the plugin Jim linked to, http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/a-new-and-improved-jquery-idle-timeout-plugin/ .  Create and link to a Javascript file and include it site wide.  Follow the documentation in the link for the plugin.  It's fairly thorough.

It's also in your best interest to set any cookies associated with the session (if there are any) to timeout after 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

there is also a JQuery plug-in called idle timeout that works great.  Set two or three parameters, including where to send people when they timeout.  Here is the link http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/a-new-and-improved-jquery-idle-timeout-plugin/